# React router v4 history, is there a way to get the url you are navigating from?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In older versions of React Router, the state had a redirectPath state object that you were able to get the previous URL from. In the new version this is no longer the case. When navigating to a new URL via history.push, all that shows up is the new URL, with no apparent way to get the URL that you navigated from previously. Is there some functionality either in React Router or the history package itself that allows you to get the previous URL?

We are using goBack and that seems to work but if the user is going to a page out of the app (e.g. google) and go back to the app the goBack function will route to google again. How can we fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You could push extra information in `state: {}` like

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/about', state: { fromHome: true } }}>About</Link>
```

Then when route has changed, you could access `state` object and check how user has navigated to your route.

Today I created the package `react-router-last-location` which provides:

- `withLastLocation()`, higher order component which pass `lastLocation` as a prop to your component
- `<LastLocationProvider />` component which should used inside `<Router />`.

Example usage

**An entry point of your app**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LastLocationProvider } from 'react-router-last-location';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import Contact from './pages/Contact';
import Logger from './components/Logger';

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <LastLocationProvider>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />

        <hr />

        <Logger />
      </div>
    </LastLocationProvider>
  </Router>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**A component which should have access to the last location**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withLastLocation } from 'react-router-last-location';

const Logger = ({ lastLocation }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Logger!</h2>
    <pre>
      {JSON.stringify(lastLocation)}
    </pre>
  </div>
);

export default withLastLocation(Logger);
```

You can install it from npm

```
npm install react-router-last-location --save
```

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-last-location
- https://github.com/hinok/react-router-last-location

Comment: I have question. What property can I use to check where the route is planning to go before hand? I want to be sure that the goBack only routes to my app and not to external urls.

Comment: Just check if `lastLocation !== null`. It tracks only route changes in your application. It doesn't access browser history, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/8nx3unp9/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Checking your component is pretty much the same examples that I was follow in other sites. I did not use your component because it has an error when my app starts. I will keep trying and check if I can find an answer. Thanks

Comment: @RichardValdivieso I fixed it in 1.0.1. It should work right now. If you want, you can give a try.